# Is it possible to have email addresses encrypted in ApplicationServices DB?

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-membership

For additional security to keep email addresses private in a project I am working on, I would like to have all emails stored in our database encrypted. However, we are using the Asp.Net Membership provider, and emails appear in clear text in the Email column of table aspnet_Membership. Is their way to achieve this? Ideally, a simple way.

Comment: There's nothing simple about encryption. Not because of the encryption itself... if you encrypt the emails you'll have to protect your secret or manage your keys. Have you thought about how you'll do either of those?

Comment: @EstebanAraya: Well, I know there is no perfect solution, but I was simply planning to put the keys in the code. Once compiled, it is not as obvious to find them. Also, it is not because someone has access to the database that that person has access to the DLLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a custom provider and just add the small amount of code to encrypt the email address.

they released source for the ASP.net Provider

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/13/442772.aspx

if you download the ProviderToolkitSamples.msi

Use the SQLMembershipProvider.cs for the membership provider on line 366 it is storing the email address you can encrypt it before calling the insert stored procedure.

you will also need to decrypt it when retrieving it from the DB as well .

Here is a good article on Encryption I would make sure you include a Salt with the email address so that it is more secure.

http://hectorcorrea.com/blog/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-a-string-in-C-Sharp

Hope that helps!