# Source Code for the Built-in ASP.NET 4 Membership Providers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

i want do some modifications in asp.net membership provider , i found [the source code for  the Built-in ASP.NET 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/13/442772.aspx) , but i want the Built-in ASP.NET **4**

thank you

Comment: Why do you want the source for the membership providers?

Comment: i want encrypt users mail and to be able to write custom provider.

Comment: This question might come in handy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331270/is-it-possible-to-have-email-addresses-encrypted-in-applicationservices-db

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its late, but hope it can help somebody who looks for that question :)

In ASP.NET 4 the default provider is ExtendedMembershipProvider - the default is SimpleMembershipProvider and they lives in WebMatrix.

You can find their source code in codeplex at the ASP.NET source code.

ExtendedMembershipProvider: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/553690ac9488#src/WebMatrix.WebData/ExtendedMembershipProvider.cs

SimpleMembershipProvider; http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/553690ac9488#src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs

Answer (score 0):

Use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to extract the source yourself directly from the Assembly.

ILSpy is an assembly browser and decompiler tool that helps you to reconstruct the code from any .NET assembly by retranslating the MSIL code.

You can use the SQLMembershipProvider as a template for your own provider, which you will find in the GAC in System.Web.Security.

Apart from that you can try your luck by searching the [ASP.NET reference sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) (which is the released .NET source code, including .NET 4). I am not sure however if the security classes are in there.

Comment: If you don't copy the code, but use it as a template and to see how MS implements his membership provider, I cannot see how there should be anything illegal about it. Please see the edit to my answer.